# Else in For Loop example

Tags: python

In the image attached, when i=3, why does the "break" take us to the final `print("Out side the loop")`? Why doesn't it jump to the part:

```
else: 
    print ("Loop terminates with success")?
```

I am struggling to understand this.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Because that's exactly how [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) works: *loop’s `else` clause runs when __no__ `break` occurs.*

Comment: @LouieC it will also print that if `S` was of size 1...

Answer (score 1):

[`for...else` loops only run the `else` when the loop terminates normally and a `break` is not encountered](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html). So, it skips the `else` since the loop was ended early.

Comment: ... wich is a dupe ...